# Parameter is not valid exception and ResourceManager

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, gdi+, embedded-resource

Clients of an Winforms .Net 4 application I wrote are now frequently reporting crashes due to to the 'parameter is not valid' error.

All the 'images' are small actually resource icons (16x16 px), and there is not that many. They are all retrieved with the resource manager, and pretty much all of them are assigned to buttons via designer generated code

The ResourceManager seems to instantiate a new Bitmap whenever I use it to retrieve an icon resource. So these are not disposed explicitely.

I've tried looking at the number of GDI Objects, and the number of user handles. The number of handles is stable, and the number of GDI objects seems to slowly increment: a few more in use after I open/close ( and dispose)  modal forms in the application.

- Is the parameter not valid due to the number of GDI objects being to high?
- If yes, is it caused by the ResourceManager?
- Do I have to explicitly release the resources created by the resource manager?
- If no, where does the Parameter is not valid come from?

Here when I'm changing the displayed icon on a toolstripmenuitem

```
System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid.
   at System.Drawing.Image.get_RawFormat()
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.set_Image(Image value)
```

Corresponding code:

```
tsbExpand.Image = global::MyProject.Properties.Resources.arrow_in;
```

Here it is with a picture box used to display an icon

```
System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid.
  at System.Drawing.Image.get_FrameDimensionsList()
  at System.Drawing.ImageAnimator.CanAnimate(Image image)
  at System.Drawing.ImageAnimator.ImageInfo..ctor(Image image)
  at System.Drawing.ImageAnimator.Animate(Image image, EventHandler   onFrameChangedHandler)
  at System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox.Animate(Boolean animate)
  at System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox.Animate()
  at System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox.OnParentChanged(EventArgs e)
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.AssignParent(Control value)
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection.Add(Control value)
```

Corresponding code:

```
this.pcbIcon.Image = global::MyProject.Properties.Resources.information;
```

Thanks

EDIT 19/02

I remember that I added the piece of code below (taken from 
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/513764/Repainting-WinForms-windows-safely-inside-a-proces) before noticing an increase in the Parameter is not valid problem. I'm not sure this is related

```
public static class WinFormUtils
{
   /// <summary> Processes all Paint events only </summary>
   public static void DoPaintEvents()
   {
       //MessageFilter registration
       Application.AddMessageFilter(PaintMessageFilter.Instance);
       //Process messages in the queue
       Application.DoEvents();
       //MessageFilter desregistration
       Application.RemoveMessageFilter(PaintMessageFilter.Instance);
   }

   /// <summary> Custom message filter </summary>
   private class PaintMessageFilter : IMessageFilter
   {
       static public IMessageFilter Instance = new PaintMessageFilter();

       #region IMessageFilter Members

       /// <summary> Message filter function </summary>
       public bool PreFilterMessage(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
       {
               return (m.Msg != 0x000F); //WM_PAINT -> we only let WM_PAINT messages through
       }

       #endregion
   }
}
```

Edit 27/10/2016: The parameter is not valid was indeed caused by the piece of code above. So don't mess up with Windows messages if you don't know what you are doing !

Answer (score 0):

> Is the parameter not valid due to the number of GDI objects being to high?

Yes, that's pretty likely.  The quality of the exception is poor, GDI+ does not generate good error codes.  "Parameter not valid" does not mean much more than "it did not work".  With having too many GDI objects or running out of desktop heap space being the primary "it did not work" reason.

> If yes, is it caused by the ResourceManager?

Not exactly.  When you obtain an image resource then you become the owner of the object.  And it is your job to call its Dispose() method.  This is rarely done and in practice does not cause trouble.  Except when you create a program that never puts enough pressure on the GC heap.  The kind of program that uses lots of controls and graphics but does not manage a lot of data.  If you don't get enough gen#2 collections then the finalizers of those objects won't run and the native operating system object won't get destroyed.

> Do I have to explicitly release the resources created by the resource manager?

Yes.

That GDI Object counter in Task Manager is the one that keeps you honest.  Don't forget to also look at USER Objects, another classic troublemaker.  Calling GC.Collect() periodically is a quick fix for the GDI Object count.  Not unreasonable if you just don't use enough GC heap.  Always get a second opinion from a memory profiler, it knows best and we're just guessing at it when we can't see a report.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Would you know if the piece of code I added (edit 19/02) could be responsible? It's hard to test as I don't have the problem on my machine.